# Trouble outputting PHP cookie's value

Tags: php, cookies, output

I have an array of cookies: access[userid], access[seriesid], access[token]

Thus far, I have assigned values to each of them, and I am having no issue doing so. My issue is when I am trying to retrieve the value of each of these cookies.

For instance, I have assigned the cookie access[userid] a value like so:

```
$userid = "matt";
setcookie("access[userid]", $userid, time()+(300));
```

And later on I attempt to output the value of this cookie in the body of the webpage:

```
echo "You are already logged in as $_COOKIE['access[userid]'].";
```

I have tried several other approaches, but none of them are working:

```
$username = $_COOKIE["access[userid]"];
echo "You are already logged in as $username.";
```

Is something wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid using square brackets in your cookie name, you're defining a cookie variable in an array notation, try

```
echo "You are already logged in as {$_COOKIE['access']['userid']}";
```

or use

```
setcookie("access_userid", $userid, time()+(300));
echo "You are already logged in as {$_COOKIE['access_userid']}";
```

This behavior is the same as form name attributes to array structures

http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays

Comment: If you're happy with this answer, please flag it as your accepted answer to the question. For future debugging try print_r($_COOKIE) or var_dump($_COOKIE)